# Webkit text-shadow rendering artifacts

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have an issue with text-shadow on webkit-based browsers. When I use light text on dark background, text-shadow looks darker than background.

```
background: #3c3745;
color: #514a5d;
text-shadow: 0 0 100px;
```

[image: Example screenshot]

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rs2oy9y/)

Am I missing something? How can I get it looking like in Firefox?

Comment: You can set the color text-color? "text-color: black 0px 0px 100px".

Comment: @Persijn I don't want black text-shadow. I want shadow of same color as text. Code `text-shadow: 0 0 100px #514a5d;` does just the same as in my example.